# ¿Cuál es el correcto orden que debe tener una oración con la palabra "por defecto"?

Tags: orden-de-palabras

Para mí, cualquiera de las siguientes opciones es válida, pero ¿existe una correcta?

Ejemplo 1:

- El módulo de Python sqlite3 **por defecto** emite una sentencia "BEGIN".
- El módulo de Python sqlite3 emite **por defecto** una sentencia "BEGIN".

Ejemplo 2:

- La librería subyacente sqlite3 **por defecto** opera en modo "autocommit".
- La librería subyacente sqlite3 opera en modo "autocommit" **por defecto**.

Comment: Yo creo que pondría la expresión "por defecto" entre comas en la primera oración de cada ejemplo. Y sin duda me quedo con el orden de la segunda en el Ejemplo 2.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance of Spanish technology terms, but am I correct to assume this is equivalent to "by default"?

Comment: @cuevero yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Resumen**: el orden es muy libre, y todos los ejemplos proporcionados son correctos.

Usando la terminología de la *[Nueva gramática de la lengua española](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/buscar.cgi)* (NGLE), "por defecto" es un *complemento circunstancial*, que es un tipo de *adjunto adverbial*. Los adjuntos (explicados en el **§39.1a**) son

> modificadores no seleccionados o no exigidos – casi siempre optativos –

y "por defecto" es un adjunto adverbial porque cumple la función de un adverbio (modifica el verbo). Sobre la posición sintáctica de los adjuntos adverbiales, la NGLE dice en el **§39.4a** (**énfasis** mío):

> La posición de los adjuntos adverbiales se aborda en los §30.2q y ss., donde se muestra que **pueden ocupar la posición inicial del grupo verbal, la medial, la final, e incluso aparecer en posición extraoracional**, en la que adquieren varios significados.

Es decir, todos los ejemplos que das son correctos. El grupo verbal es el predicado ('emite una sentencia "BEGIN"'), y el adjunto adverbial "por defecto" puede ocupar en él la posición **inicial**:

- El módulo de Python sqlite3 **por defecto** emite una sentencia "BEGIN".

**medial**:

- El módulo de Python sqlite3 emite **por defecto** una sentencia "BEGIN".

**final**:

- El módulo de Python sqlite3 emite una sentencia "BEGIN" **por defecto**.

e incluso aparecer en posición **extraoracional**:

- **Por defecto**, el módulo de Python sqlite3 emite una sentencia "BEGIN".

La NGLE dice que, en algunos casos, cambiar el orden cambia el significado de la frase (el énfasis se aplica a distintas partes de la oración), pero tengo que decir que en estos dos ejemplos, la diferencia, si la hay, es muy pequeña. Las posiciones más naturales para mí son la medial y la final, lo que concuerda con el **§30.2q** que dice que en el ejemplo "Hablaba rápidamente", el adverbio *rápidamente* ocupa su "posición natural".